editPost without undo entry
I am updating my post status with following snippet:
dispatch("core/editor").editPost( {
    status: 'draft' 
} );

My problem is, that this action creates a new undo-entry. Is it possible to avoid this (eg. "undo: false" or something similar)?
Thank you in advance

Yes,  editPost is a wrapper around editEntityRecord which according to the core/data docs takes an options object that supports undoIgnore:


options Object: Options for the edit.
options.undoIgnore [boolean]: Whether to ignore the edit in undo history or not.


While you could use this, generally the need to use it implies a mistake or misunderstanding somewhere, or that the draft status is being set too late and should be set earlier.
A Warning: Editing vs Saving
Using editPost and editEntityRecord to set your post status to draft might not edit the database, it just changes the block editors internal state. It still needs to be saved/published to take effect.
This is why we have a saveEntityRecord function too, and it's how the editor knows what posts/templates to list in the checkbox list when you click publish ( e.g. it'll prompt if you want to update nav menus and synced templates etc )
For this reason, you might want to keep the undo/redo record.

Thank you. Your solution worked.
I just need a "revert to draft" button at another location. Is this the wrong approach?

in this case I wouldn't disable undo, it can be clicked accidentally, but you're also implying that this action is immediate which it is not. You haven't set the post to draft on the site, just the edited state in the editor, it still needs to be saved, in the same way that editing the posts title in the editor doesn't change it on the site unless you save/publish

I've updated the answer with that as a warning
